# How to SSH from Perl script from windows machine to EC2 machine

Tags: windows, perl, ssh, amazon-ec2, tunnel

I want to set and ssh tunnel between my windows machine and EC2 machine, I want to use perl for that, according to this [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~syagi/Net-SSH-Tunnel-0.03/lib/Net/SSH/Tunnel.pm), I have to use ./driver.pl script which I couldn't find.

I use this string to ssh to my machine using command line.

`ssh -2 -p 22 username@id-address -i keyfile.ssh -L p8600/Localhost/3306`

I tried this from this [post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1028223) but I get this error:

`my $ssh_pid= open("ssh -2 -p 22 username@id-address -i keyfile.ssh -L p8600/Localhost/3306 |") or die;`

`Can't use string ("ssh -2 -p 22 username@id-address"...) as a symbol ref while "
strict refs" in use at .\start.pl line 39.
D:\DESKTOP\JEFF_SHIH\MAPPING_FILE_GENERATOR>`

how can I translate the above string to perl or fix the string above to get ride of the error.
I installed Net::SSH::Tunnel

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt `open` works the way you expect it to on Windows-systems.

Comment: Windows or *nix, `open` returns a success flag, not a pid.  `open`'s 1st parameter is always a file handle, not a random shell command.  `perldoc perlopentut`, `perldoc -f open`  are great starting points to learning how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Net::SSH::Perl` to avoid tricky (on Windows!) dependencies to ssh-binaries. This module is written completely in Perl, so it should work on any platform. [Net::SSH::Perl](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aPerl)