# Perl 5.20.1 version downloaded.How to set up the path?

Tags: windows, perl, ssh, strawberry-perl

I downloaded strawberry `perl 5.20.1` to my windows 7.
 I also installed cpan module.
However when I run the program, it still shows that cannot find [`NET::OpenSSH`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH)
Should I make correct path in environment variables on my computer? If yes, how an what is the correct path?

Should I use something else instead?

I just want to login to Linux box from windows 7

Answer (score 2):

From [`perldoc Net::OpenSSH`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH),

> On the other hand, Net::OpenSSH does not work on Windows, not even under Cygwin.
>   [..]
>
> Net::OpenSSH does not work on Windows. OpenSSH multiplexing feature requires passing file handles through sockets, something that is not supported by any version of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

As documented in [`Net::OpenSSH` #Known Issues](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#Known-issues)

> #### Known issues
>
> Net::OpenSSH does not work on Windows. OpenSSH multiplexing feature requires passing file handles through sockets, something that is not supported by any version of Windows.

#### Alternatives

For alternatives, look at:

1. [`Net::SSH::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl) as suggested in [How to SSH from Perl script from windows machine to EC2 machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023388/how-to-ssh-from-perl-script-from-windows-machine-to-ec2-machine).
2. [`Net::SSH2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2) as suggested in [Unable to install the perl module Net::SSH::Perl on windows 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329617/unable-to-install-the-perl-module-netsshperl-on-windows-64-bit).

Comment: ... or [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Any) which provides a subset of Net::OpenSSH API on top of Net::SSH2.